# Create input with maxlength based on database size

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to write a text_field in my view, that **automatically** respects the size of database field?

My migration:

```
t.string :name, limit: 100
```

My view:

```
<%= f.text_field :name %>
```

Comment: Have you tried this? `<%= f.text_field :name, size: 100 %>`

Comment: Lets suppose that I need to change the size of this field. I dont want to check all my code looking for this "100" fixed code.

Comment: Maybe any property in the activerecord object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is a way to get it done. Write a code inside the `/helper` directory, and put the method inside the :

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def column_info model_name, field_name, option
    model_name.constantize.column_types[field_name].public_send option
  end 
end
```

Now, use this helper method anywhere inside the view..

```
<%= f.text_field :name, size: column_info('Person', :name, :limit) || 100 %>
```

Comment: I had to change "column_types" to "columns_hash"

Answer (score 0):

Make it a constant in your model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  MAX_NAME_SIZE = 100

  validates :name, length: { maximum: MAX_NAME_SIZE }
end
```

And use it in a form:

```
<%= f.text_field :name, size: User::MAX_NAME_SIZE %>
```

Comment: I found this: Person.columns_hash["name"].limit. It's safe to use?